# The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I'm getting this 2 errors repeatedly when I'm trying to connect eclipse with **sql server** through **jdbc**. Could anyone help me with this or explain why am I getting this?

```
1. The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed.  
2. The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption.
```

Thank you.

```
String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
String connString      ="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/databaseName=Engg_Street;instance=SQLSERVER;encrypt=true;     trustServerCertificate=true";
String username = "Vijayalakshmi";
String password = "";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
```

Comment: Well, the error is quite clear: JDBC can't connect to your database using SSL. Is your database configured to use SSL on port 1433?

Comment: Any code you are using? Help us to help you.

Comment: Hey I have posted the code in my new ques,can you help??

Comment: @user2810964 - Don't do that!  Edit this Question to add your code here!

Comment: @Stephen C Yes I have done it..

Answer (score 73):

```
You need to Go to Start > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager
```

When it opens Go to

```
SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLExpress
```

Where you'll find the Protocol TCP/IP, if disabled then Enable it Click on TCP/IP, You'll find its properties.

In this properties **Remove All the TCP Dynamic Ports and Add value of 1433 to all TCP Port
and restart your SQL Server Services > SQL Server**

And Its Done...

Comment: this is the error"the request failed or the service didn't respond in timely fashion"..

Comment: Database installation error，eelete the registry, reinstall it

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Someone should mark this answer as correct.

Comment: This also worked for me! 
To clarify @sunysen's answer, edit the entry at the bottom of the list titled "IPAll". Clear the field "TCP Dynamic Ports" and set "TCP Port" to 1433.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running SQLSERVER EXPRESS:

Use "SQL Server Configuration Manager" or write "mmc.exe" on Win+R and search "SQL Server Network Configuration", in the "Protocols for SQLEXPRESS" enable the option TCP/IP

I hope than this works for somebody!!

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of issue - you can resolve by checking whether all sql server related services are running or not.

```
TO check Start -> Run -> services.msc 
check services related to sql as
SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server Browser
SQL Server Integration Services 10.0
SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server VSS Writer
```

Start all the above services. and set to start up type to Automatic.

SQL Active Directory Helper Service is not required to keep running.

It can used to deal with error SQL server connection error 2 
and 
with 
he TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused:

Answer (score -1):

It can used to deal with error SQL server connection error 2 and with he TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8_jjkeulEw

or please check if the table name is duplicated, i changed the table name --> problem solved