# SQL Server - JDBC Connection

Tags: java, sql-server

I've installed a SQLServer 2014 in a Windows10 box. I'm new to MSSQL administration. I've connected successfully to the instance with Server Management, and processes are running, but I'm unable to connect to instance from a java tool. I've configured instance port manually:

[image]

Then I've checked with resource monitor and I'm not able to identify the process queue SQLSERVER is running and seems that port 1433 is not listening for connections.

So, when I try to connect from java tool I'm getting the following error:
[image]

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the port being used by some other process? Also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18981672/1004631

Comment: It sounds more like an SQL server problem than a Java problem.  You might want to post to https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Are you connected locally or remotely? I mean, your Management Studio was on the same pc where the server is? And your java tool, is it on the same pc or on another?

Comment: The error message says you tried to connect localhost, i.e. locally, so for what purpose did you write a port to your connection string? When you connect locally, it's a shared memory protocol that is used, not tcp ip

Comment: And what is your instance name? Is it default instance or named instance?  What did you put in your connection string when your connection was successful?

Comment: yes, both are in same box

Comment: port does not appear in proccess monitor, nor proccess

Comment: Might be Windows firewall: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2011/06/how-to-open-firewall-port-1433-for-sql-server-database-engine-for-use-with-scom-or-anything-else/

Comment: no windows firewall enabled in this box

Comment: I have just put all the network interfaces in SQLServer Configuration Manager static at port 1433, but no process running in this port

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it forcing to listen on address 127.0.0.1 and only this address on a different port.

Hope it helps