# errors while connecting java with sql server 2017

Tags: java, sql-server

```
public class RDF2Connection {

     static Connection connection=null;
     final static String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-Q5K9FE6:1433;" +
             "databaseName=RDFDB;";
    public static Connection getRdf2Connected(){

            try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "sa", "root");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return connection;
        }

}
```

---

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
>   to the host DESKTOP-Q5K9FE6, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection
>   refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties.
>   Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and
>   accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP
>   connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:257)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2385)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:567)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1955)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1616)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1447)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:788)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1187)
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>         at com.rdf2.databaseconnection.RDF2Connection.getRdf2Connected(RDF2Connection.java:22)
>         at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:53)
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:54)
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Possible duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981279/the-tcp-ip-connection-to-the-host-localhost-port-1433-has-failed)

Comment: Check to see if the netbios name resolve to the server. Try use ipadress instead? Or that the Mssqlserver is running.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed). Have you added the dll?

Comment: `Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall`: Pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make sure this the the correct port

this is the true answer 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if the SQL Server is only listening on an IPv6 port?  If so you can use the following

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true");
```

That would be my only suggestion as far as code changes.  Possibly try and use the IP as opposed to the name.  If that doesn't work you need to go to your SQL Server and verify that it accepts TCP/IP connections, or check your local firewall settings.  At that point the question would be more appropriate for server exchange.

Comment: I haven't worked with SQL Server in a while.  Just build a new program with that line and see if you still get the same error